# C++ How does this Syntax Work?

Tags: c++

I'm reading through some source code, and I've found some wacky-looking code. Here is one example of a single function that's been declared an used, and this syntax has been used a lot.

```
HINSTANCE hlib = LoadLibrary(L"ps3tmapi.dll");

//initial definition
typedef int(__cdecl *ProcessInfo)(int,UINT32, UINT32*, SNPS3PROCESSINFO*);

//some function created using what's above
ProcessInfo GetProcessInfo = (ProcessInfo)GetProcAddress(hlib, "SNPS3ProcessInfo");

//use of this function
GetProcessInfo(Target,ProcessID,buffsz,info);
```

This is by no means in order, just snippets from the source code. So, what is this syntax doing exactly? I'm specifically scratching my head over the second line where `GetProcessInfo` is being declared.

To make things clear, I'm not so worried about the meaning of this code (as multiple things from here are defined elsewhere so you can't know what they are), I just haven't yet see this kind of syntax. So if someone could explain it, then that would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: look up "function pointer"

Comment: See the canonical example at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212.aspx. The 2nd line typedef's the prototype of the function pointer expected to be returned by GetProcAddres. In other words, `hlib` probably has an exported function "SNPS3ProcessInfo" declared as `int __cdecl SNPS3ProcessInfo(int, UINT32, UINT32*, SNPS3PROCESSINFO*);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
typedef int(__cdecl *ProcessInfo)(int,UINT32, UINT32*, SNPS3PROCESSINFO*);
```

This declares a type called ProcessInfo which represents a function returning an `int` and accepting 4 arguments `int, UINT32, UINT32*, SNPS3PROCESSINFO*`.

Now `GetProcAddress` returns a memory address which is the address of a function somewhere in memory. To be able to use it you must cast it to a function, that's the purpose of the second line

```
ProcessInfo GetProcessInfo = (ProcessInfo)GetProcAddress(hlib, "SNPS3ProcessInfo");
```

Declare a variable named `GetProcessInfo` which is a function of signature `ProcessInfo` and with the value of the address returned by `GetProcAddress`.

After this you can use`GetProcessInfo` as if you had

```
int GetProcessInfo(int,UINT32, UINT32*, SNPS3PROCESSINFO*);
```

defined in your code.

Comment: Okay.. I'm beginning to understand. But if all `GetProcessInfo` is, is just a memory address casted to `ProcessInfo` then what does `GetProcessInfo` do with the arguments? Like when you put in `int,UINT32, UINT32*, SNPS3PROCESSINFO*`, what does `GetProcessInfo` actually _do_ with them?

Comment: A function is nothing more than a memory address, parameters are pushed onto stack or placed inside registers according to calling conventions, before jumping through a call to the function address. So it's under all effects a normal function. Indeed you can see `__cdecl` which specifies the calling convention of the typedef function defined to let the compiler write the correct call preamble.

Answer (score 2):

the example demonstrates how to load a dll and call one of the exported functions.

The signature of the exported function is set in below syntax.

```
typedef int(__cdecl *ProcessInfo)(int,UINT32, UINT32*, SNPS3PROCESSINFO*);
```

Below syntax, instructs the runtime to use the dll loaded by "LoadLibrary" call, and fetch a pointer to the exported function "SNPS3ProcessInfo" and assign to "GEtProcessInfo"

```
//some function created using what's above

ProcessInfo GetProcessInfo = (ProcessInfo)GetProcAddress(hlib, "SNPS3ProcessInfo");
```